# Can no longer connect to Wi-fi after update on EndeavourOS

Tags: wifi, realtek, dkms, endeavouros

Recently I've been using EndeavourOS with [these](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rtl8723du-dkms-git) wifi drivers, due to mine (Realtek 8723du) not being officially supported. They work fine until recent kernel update *5.19.11-arch1-1* broke them. I tried removing them from the DKMS tree and reinstalling them, even compiled them *[by source](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723du)*, and they still do not work. Here is the device seen in `lsusb`:

`Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:d723 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n WLAN Adapter`

It does not show up in `rfkill list`:

`[maxintosh@maestro ~]$ rfkill list`

`0: hci0: Bluetooth`

`Soft blocked: no`
`Hard blocked: no`

I am willing to provide any extra information if need be. *(Also apologies for poor formatting)*

*Edit: Today I booted up my laptop and it seems to work again. I am not sure why this is the cause. I am willing to post the journald if needed, as I find this interesting. I am worried this will happen again during another update.*